# Is it possible to move/copy files from Amazon glacier to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I've backed up some files in Glacier previously, but now I want them in S3 storage instead (where I may then use infrequent, or glacier storage class). Rather than upload them all I'd like to just copy them server side. From what I can see of the glacier API I'm not sure I can (just download the files and then re-upload).

Does anyone know it I can just copy Amazon side?

Comment: Glacier stores it's data in tapes as I have read so, as it's not really in Amazon servers AFAIK you can't just copy it. BTW Glacier charges you more if you need to recover the files quickly.

Comment: I would guess it uses tapes for long term, but that's my guess and not actually relevant. If you make a retrieval request it can take 4+ hours for the data to be ready to download. I was just wondering if there's a way to request a copy to S3 which may also take several hours to start, buy then happen behind the scene.  Sadly it doesn't look like there is. Even on FTTC I only get about 4Mbps upload so 70GB takes a while!

Comment: To clarify: you are talking about archives stored directly in Glacier, and not S3 objects that have transitioned to the Glacier storage class... correct?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes - correct.  This is an old backup that I made in glacier, that I now want in S3 (to use the Infrequent Access storage instead)